# Flask app doesn't start successfully after deploying on IBM Toolchain

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, toolchain

The same code worked perfectly on my local machine and I could visit the deployed app at localhost:5000. However, when I uploaded the files on GitHub and then deployed them on IBM Toolchain, I'm unable to start the app successfully.

Let me explain what I'm doing in brief. I'm using IBM's Cloud Object storage to access a .csv file and then continue to perform ML predictions and display the results. The user can also upload his/her own .csv file by connecting to Cloud Object storage. I have checked them on my local machine and as mentioned, they worked perfectly fine.

Yes, I have mentioned the proper requirements, Procfile, manifest.yml.

Here is the link to my git repo where you can check out if there are any errors -

https://github.com/sthitaprajna-mishra/churn_prediction_v1_git

The logs:

```
Preparing to start the job...
Pipeline image: latest
Preparing the build artifacts...
Pulling pipeline base image latest ...
cf login -a "https://api.eu-gb.cf.cloud.ibm.com" -u apikey -p "****" -o "smishrav2@gmail.com" -s "dev" 
API endpoint: https://api.eu-gb.cf.cloud.ibm.com
Authenticating...
OK

Targeted org smishrav2@gmail.com

Targeted space dev



API endpoint:   https://api.eu-gb.cf.cloud.ibm.com (API version: 2.147.0)
User:           smishrav2@gmail.com
Org:            smishrav2@gmail.com
Space:          dev
Showing health and status for app churn_vone in org smishrav2@gmail.com / space dev as smishrav2@gmail.com...

FAILED
App 'churn_vone' not found.
Pushing from manifest to org smishrav2@gmail.com / space dev as smishrav2@gmail.com...
Using manifest file /home/pipeline/8f55659f-e9c8-4d3e-bb5e-4ec397afe427/manifest.yml
Getting app info...
Creating app with these attributes...
+ name:         churn_vone
  path:         /home/pipeline/8f55659f-e9c8-4d3e-bb5e-4ec397afe427
  buildpacks:
+   https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack.git
+ command:      python app.py
+ memory:       25M
  routes:
+   churnvone-interested-fox.eu-gb.mybluemix.net

Creating app churn_vone...
Mapping routes...
Comparing local files to remote cache...
Packaging files to upload...
Uploading files...

 0 B / 105.87 KiB    0.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00%
 105.87 KiB / 105.87 KiB  100.00% 2s

Waiting for API to complete processing files...

Staging app and tracing logs...
   Cell 883bbd38-6bc5-4dca-a216-7f24c8afa166 creating container for instance d9606cdb-c70e-48f9-a216-ed8c07947921
   Cell 883bbd38-6bc5-4dca-a216-7f24c8afa166 successfully created container for instance d9606cdb-c70e-48f9-a216-ed8c07947921
   Downloading app package...
   Downloaded app package (849.3K)
   -----> Download go 1.12.4
   -----> Running go build supply
   /tmp/buildpackdownloads/c011a0fe8e55069cdbeb0a3d00e21875 ~
   ~
   -----> Python Buildpack version 1.7.13
   -----> Supplying Python
   -----> Installing python 3.8.2
          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/python/python-3.8.2-linux-x64-cflinuxfs3-580151dd.tgz]
   -----> Installing pip-pop 0.1.4
          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/manual-binaries/pip-pop/pip-pop-0.1.4-0a3b0f1b.tar.gz]
   -----> Running Pip Install
          Collecting Flask>=1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f2/28/2a03252dfb9ebf377f40fba6a7841b47083260bf8bd8e737b0c6952df83f/Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94kB)
          Collecting cloudant==2.4.0 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/42/9c4359e738cd6018829e8779962eb78e24323239e028d6c190507125a65b/cloudant-2.4.0.tar.gz (50kB)
          Collecting ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/6d/caa16a1a85af26bb2c4902644f43b233a8db2a7d7485792c25601f67a5ae/ibm-cos-sdk-2.3.2.tar.gz (49kB)
          Collecting urllib3==1.24.2 (from -r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 4))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/1c/59cca3abf96f991f2ec3131a4ffe72ae3d9ea1f5894abe8a9c5e3c77cfee/urllib3-1.24.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (131kB)
          Collecting Jinja2>=2.10.1 (from Flask>=1.0.0->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/9e/f663a2aa66a09d838042ae1a2c5659828bb9b41ea3a6efa20a20fd92b121/Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB)
          Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24 (from Flask>=1.0.0->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ae/44b03b253d6fade317f32c24d100b3b35c2239807046a4c953c7b89fa49e/itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
          Collecting click>=5.1 (from Flask>=1.0.0->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/3d/fa76db83bf75c4f8d338c2fd15c8d33fdd7ad23a9b5e57eb6c5de26b430e/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82kB)
          Collecting Werkzeug>=0.15 (from Flask>=1.0.0->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/94/5f7079a0e00bd6863ef8f1da638721e9da21e5bacee597595b318f71d62e/Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298kB)
          Collecting requests<3.0.0,>=2.7.0 (from cloudant==2.4.0->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/70/1935c770cb3be6e3a8b78ced23d7e0f3b187f5cbfab4749523ed65d7c9b1/requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
          Collecting ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.*,>=2.0.0 (from ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/f0/ebb57ccf2d3dc567988cea6a6ba778ebbf96bc4f40039866757dd97cb80a/ibm-cos-sdk-core-2.6.2.tar.gz (787kB)
          Collecting ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer==2.*,>=2.0.0 (from ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/5e/11d12801a51cb74272d4f6072b4da5570d6739137e11f6573b6c043b3160/ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer-2.6.2.tar.gz (131kB)
          Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=1.0.0->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/20/f6d7648c81cb84815d0be935d5c74cd1cc0239e43eadb1a61062d34b6543/MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
          Collecting idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.7.0->cloudant==2.4.0->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/e3/afebe61c546d18fb1709a61bee788254b40e736cff7271c7de5de2dc4128/idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
          Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.7.0->cloudant==2.4.0->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
          Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.7.0->cloudant==2.4.0->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/2b/26e37a4b034800c960a00c4e1b3d9ca5d7014e983e6e729e33ea2f36426c/certifi-2020.4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157kB)
          Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.*,>=2.0.0->ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/43/1e939e1fcd87b827fe192d0c9fc25b48c5b3368902bfb913de7754b0dc03/jmespath-0.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
          Collecting docutils<0.16,>=0.10 (from ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.*,>=2.0.0->ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/cd/a6aa959dca619918ccb55023b4cb151949c64d4d5d55b3f4ffd7eee0c6e8/docutils-0.15.2-py3-none-any.whl (547kB)
          Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.*,>=2.0.0->ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227kB)
          Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.*,>=2.0.0->ibm-cos-sdk==2.3.2->-r /tmp/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
            Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/eb/1f97cb97bfc2390a276969c6fae16075da282f5058082d4cb10c6c5c1dba/six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
          Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, click, Werkzeug, Flask, idna, chardet, urllib3, certifi, requests, cloudant, jmespath, docutils, six, python-dateutil, ibm-cos-sdk-core, ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer, ibm-cos-sdk
            WARNING: The script flask is installed in '/tmp/contents945626316/deps/0/python/bin' which is not on PATH.
            Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
            WARNING: The script chardetect is installed in '/tmp/contents945626316/deps/0/python/bin' which is not on PATH.
            Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
            Running setup.py install for cloudant: started
              Running setup.py install for cloudant: finished with status 'done'
            Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk-core: started
              Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk-core: finished with status 'done'
            Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer: started
              Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer: finished with status 'done'
            Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk: started
              Running setup.py install for ibm-cos-sdk: finished with status 'done'
          Successfully installed Flask-1.1.2 Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 certifi-2020.4.5.1 chardet-3.0.4 click-7.1.2 cloudant-2.4.0 docutils-0.15.2 ibm-cos-sdk-2.3.2 ibm-cos-sdk-core-2.6.2 ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer-2.6.2 idna-2.9 itsdangerous-1.1.0 jmespath-0.9.5 python-dateutil-2.8.1 requests-2.23.0 six-1.14.0 urllib3-1.24.2
          WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1 is available.
          You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
   -----> Running go build finalize
   /tmp/buildpackdownloads/c011a0fe8e55069cdbeb0a3d00e21875 ~
   ~
   Exit status 0
   Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
   Uploading droplet...
   Uploading build artifacts cache...
   Uploaded build artifacts cache (57.6M)
   Uploaded droplet (59.9M)
   Uploading complete
   Cell 883bbd38-6bc5-4dca-a216-7f24c8afa166 stopping instance d9606cdb-c70e-48f9-a216-ed8c07947921
   Cell 883bbd38-6bc5-4dca-a216-7f24c8afa166 destroying container for instance d9606cdb-c70e-48f9-a216-ed8c07947921

Waiting for app to start...
FAILED
Start unsuccessful

TIP: use 'cf logs churn_vone --recent' for more information

Finished: FAILED
```

EDIT: I must mention that on my local machine, it took quite some time to load. Is that why it's being rejected from being deployed because it takes too much time?

EDIT 2: So I installed IBM CLI, changed the timeout to 180 in manifest.yml and tried to push my app through there. After checking the error logs I realised I had forgotten to write numpy in requirements.txt. After correcting it, I pushed it again and this time I am faced with another error.

This is how my logs looked towards the end:

```
 Running setup.py install for pandas: finished with status 'done'
          Successfully installed Flask-1.1.2 Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 certifi-2020.4.5.1 chardet-3.0.4 click-7.1.2 cloudant-2.4.0 docutils-0.15.2 ibm-cos-sdk-2.3.2 ibm-cos-sdk-core-2.6.2 ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer-2.6.2 idna-2.9 itsdangerous-1.1.0 jmespath-0.9.5 joblib-0.14.1 numpy-1.14.3 pandas-0.23.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 requests-2.23.0 scikit-learn-0.22.2 scipy-1.4.1 six-1.14.0 urllib3-1.22
          WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1 is available.
          You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
   -----> Running go build finalize
   /tmp/buildpackdownloads/c011a0fe8e55069cdbeb0a3d00e21875 ~
   ~
Error staging application myChurnAppByAmlan: timed out after 15 minute(s)
FAILED
```

I used `ibmcloud cf logs myChurnAppByAmlan --recent` for more info as directed and the following logs popped up:

```
Invoking 'cf logs myChurnAppByAmlan --recent'...

Retrieving logs for app myChurnAppByAmlan in org smishrav2@gmail.com / space dev as smishrav2@gmail.com...

   2020-05-04T14:21:29.25+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T14:22:35.59+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T14:23:38.42+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T14:23:53.99+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: finished with status 'done'
   2020-05-04T14:24:01.69+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Successfully installed Flask-1.1.2 Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 certifi-2020.4.5.1 chardet-3.0.4 click-7.1.2 cloudant-2.4.0 docutils-0.15.2 ibm-cos-sdk-2.3.2 ibm-cos-sdk-core-2.6.2 ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer-2.6.2 idna-2.9 itsdangerous-1.1.0 jmespath-0.9.5 joblib-0.14.1 numpy-1.14.3 pandas-0.23.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 requests-2.23.0 scikit-learn-0.22.2 scipy-1.4.1 six-1.14.0 urllib3-1.22
   2020-05-04T14:24:02.19+0530 [STG/0] ERR        WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1 is available.
   2020-05-04T14:24:02.19+0530 [STG/0] ERR        You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
   2020-05-04T14:24:02.42+0530 [STG/0] OUT -----> Running go build finalize
   2020-05-04T14:24:02.42+0530 [STG/0] OUT /tmp/buildpackdownloads/c011a0fe8e55069cdbeb0a3d00e21875 ~
   2020-05-04T14:24:04.24+0530 [STG/0] OUT ~
   2020-05-04T14:24:28.33+0530 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 143
   2020-05-04T14:24:28.47+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell c8dbca73-4ffc-4bde-8362-0fe98e683c38 stopping instance 0f089d13-1dc2-4cca-8a0d-91eaf01307af
   2020-05-04T14:24:28.47+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell c8dbca73-4ffc-4bde-8362-0fe98e683c38 destroying container for instance 0f089d13-1dc2-4cca-8a0d-91eaf01307af
   2020-05-04T14:24:28.68+0530 [API/11] ERR Failed to stage build: staging failed
   2020-05-04T14:24:31.85+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell c8dbca73-4ffc-4bde-8362-0fe98e683c38 successfully destroyed container for instance 0f089d13-1dc2-4cca-8a0d-91eaf01307af
```

What is going wrong?

EDIT 3: As suggested, I removed the buildpack from my manifest.yml and I'm getting an unsuccessful start message, just like at the very beginning. Here are the detailed error logs:

```
Invoking 'cf logs churn_predictor --recent'...

Retrieving logs for app churn_predictor in org smishrav2@gmail.com / space dev as smishrav2@gmail.com...

   2020-05-04T17:26:02.81+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T17:27:16.85+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T17:28:27.87+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T17:29:44.22+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T17:30:49.48+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T17:31:40.76+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: finished with status 'done'
   2020-05-04T17:31:46.13+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Successfully installed Flask-1.1.2 Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 certifi-2020.4.5.1 chardet-3.0.4 click-7.1.2 docutils-0.15.2 ibm-cos-sdk-2.3.2 ibm-cos-sdk-core-2.6.2 ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer-2.6.2 idna-2.9 itsdangerous-1.1.0 jmespath-0.9.5 joblib-0.14.1 numpy-1.14.3 pandas-0.23.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 requests-2.23.0 scikit-learn-0.22.2 scipy-1.4.1 six-1.14.0 urllib3-1.22
   2020-05-04T17:31:46.53+0530 [STG/0] ERR        WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1 is available.
   2020-05-04T17:31:46.53+0530 [STG/0] ERR        You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
   2020-05-04T17:32:13.02+0530 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-05-04T17:32:13.02+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
   2020-05-04T17:32:13.02+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading build artifacts cache...
   2020-05-04T17:32:13.02+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet...
   2020-05-04T17:32:14.96+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded build artifacts cache (102.7M)
   2020-05-04T17:32:15.63+0530 [API/14] OUT Creating droplet for app with guid 13384155-a2c9-43f0-9fea-c8ced0f076a3
   2020-05-04T17:32:25.28+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded droplet (131.3M)
   2020-05-04T17:32:25.30+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading complete
   2020-05-04T17:32:25.47+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell 5eb24020-0906-4687-bead-828b98f0c9a9 stopping instance dea296d3-1e11-4670-842f-b3a4c2661643
   2020-05-04T17:32:25.47+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell 5eb24020-0906-4687-bead-828b98f0c9a9 destroying container for instance dea296d3-1e11-4670-842f-b3a4c2661643
   2020-05-04T17:32:25.98+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell 5eb24020-0906-4687-bead-828b98f0c9a9 successfully destroyed container for instance dea296d3-1e11-4670-842f-b3a4c2661643
   2020-05-04T17:32:26.47+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea creating container for instance 525fbaaa-0a49-421e-5070-0094
   2020-05-04T17:32:28.45+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea successfully created container for instance 525fbaaa-0a49-421e-5070-0094
   2020-05-04T17:32:30.08+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2020-05-04T17:32:43.50+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet (131.3M)
   2020-05-04T17:32:43.50+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2020-05-04T17:32:49.53+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 137 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T17:32:49.54+0530 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-05-04T17:32:50.05+0530 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T17:32:55.28+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea stopping instance 525fbaaa-0a49-421e-5070-0094
   2020-05-04T17:32:55.28+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea destroying container for instance 525fbaaa-0a49-421e-5070-0094
   2020-05-04T17:32:55.31+0530 [API/22] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2020-05-04T17:32:55.34+0530 [API/22] OUT App instance exited with guid 13384155-a2c9-43f0-9fea-c8ced0f076a3 payload: {"instance"=>"525fbaaa-0a49-421e-5070-0094", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 137 (out of memory)", "crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1588593775268955462, "version"=>"8227e143-287b-40f8-9696-f2b31a0b9df8"}
   2020-05-04T17:32:55.43+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f9fb4414-e768-44e9-8917-ad07c818591f creating container for instance 80de3800-7623-4bcc-5862-2170
   2020-05-04T17:32:57.91+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea successfully destroyed container for instance 525fbaaa-0a49-421e-5070-0094
   2020-05-04T17:32:58.40+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f9fb4414-e768-44e9-8917-ad07c818591f successfully created container for instance 80de3800-7623-4bcc-5862-2170
   2020-05-04T17:32:58.91+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2020-05-04T17:33:10.22+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet (131.3M)
   2020-05-04T17:33:10.22+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2020-05-04T17:33:16.26+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T17:33:16.27+0530 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-05-04T17:33:16.56+0530 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T17:33:22.14+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f9fb4414-e768-44e9-8917-ad07c818591f stopping instance 80de3800-7623-4bcc-5862-2170
   2020-05-04T17:33:22.14+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f9fb4414-e768-44e9-8917-ad07c818591f destroying container for instance 80de3800-7623-4bcc-5862-2170
   2020-05-04T17:33:22.16+0530 [API/13] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2020-05-04T17:33:22.20+0530 [API/13] OUT App instance exited with guid 13384155-a2c9-43f0-9fea-c8ced0f076a3 payload: {"instance"=>"80de3800-7623-4bcc-5862-2170", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"f9fb4414-e768-44e9-8917-ad07c818591f", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"PROXY: Exited with status 137 (out of memory); APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 1 (out of memory)", "crash_count"=>2, "crash_timestamp"=>1588593802118600216, "version"=>"8227e143-287b-40f8-9696-f2b31a0b9df8"}
   2020-05-04T17:33:22.42+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea creating container for instance 06d96ed7-fef8-4452-645b-2299
   2020-05-04T17:33:24.07+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f9fb4414-e768-44e9-8917-ad07c818591f successfully destroyed container for instance 80de3800-7623-4bcc-5862-2170
   2020-05-04T17:33:24.08+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea successfully created container for instance 06d96ed7-fef8-4452-645b-2299
   2020-05-04T17:33:24.41+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2020-05-04T17:33:28.53+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet
   2020-05-04T17:33:28.53+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2020-05-04T17:33:35.73+0530 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T17:33:35.79+0530 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-05-04T17:33:35.94+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 143 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T17:33:41.97+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea stopping instance 06d96ed7-fef8-4452-645b-2299
   2020-05-04T17:33:41.97+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea destroying container for instance 06d96ed7-fef8-4452-645b-2299
   2020-05-04T17:33:42.03+0530 [API/16] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2020-05-04T17:33:42.08+0530 [API/16] OUT App instance exited with guid 13384155-a2c9-43f0-9fea-c8ced0f076a3 payload: {"instance"=>"06d96ed7-fef8-4452-645b-2299", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"PROXY: Exited with status 137 (out of memory)", "crash_count"=>3, "crash_timestamp"=>1588593821973690477, "version"=>"8227e143-287b-40f8-9696-f2b31a0b9df8"}
   2020-05-04T17:33:43.94+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 34bac618-1a02-446d-9f26-8d5c9544f0ea successfully destroyed container for instance 06d96ed7-fef8-4452-645b-2299
   2020-05-04T17:34:36.93+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 4305ad80-962a-43de-b384-a7f5708877e4 creating container for instance 35bee15f-518e-4ecf-5634-18d3
   2020-05-04T17:34:38.39+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 4305ad80-962a-43de-b384-a7f5708877e4 successfully created container for instance 35bee15f-518e-4ecf-5634-18d3
   2020-05-04T17:34:38.54+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2020-05-04T17:34:49.14+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet (131.3M)
   2020-05-04T17:34:49.14+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2020-05-04T17:34:54.17+0530 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T17:34:54.22+0530 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-05-04T17:34:54.29+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 143 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T17:34:59.62+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 4305ad80-962a-43de-b384-a7f5708877e4 stopping instance 35bee15f-518e-4ecf-5634-18d3
   2020-05-04T17:34:59.62+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 4305ad80-962a-43de-b384-a7f5708877e4 destroying container for instance 35bee15f-518e-4ecf-5634-18d3
   2020-05-04T17:34:59.65+0530 [API/5] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2020-05-04T17:34:59.68+0530 [API/5] OUT App instance exited with guid 13384155-a2c9-43f0-9fea-c8ced0f076a3 payload: {"instance"=>"35bee15f-518e-4ecf-5634-18d3", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"4305ad80-962a-43de-b384-a7f5708877e4", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"PROXY: Exited with status 137 (out of memory)", "crash_count"=>4, "crash_timestamp"=>1588593899623282020, "version"=>"8227e143-287b-40f8-9696-f2b31a0b9df8"}
   2020-05-04T17:35:01.17+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 4305ad80-962a-43de-b384-a7f5708877e4 successfully destroyed container for instance 35bee15f-518e-4ecf-5634-18d3
```

Comment: So whats the output for 'cf logs churn_vone --recent' ?

Comment: Since I'm directly performing this on Toolchain instead of CloudFoundry, I don't know how I am supposed to use that.

Comment: You should use PORT instead of deprecated VCAP_APP_PORT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app takes a long time to start, you may want to consider setting [**timeout**](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#timeout) in your manifest.yml.

Also note that **VCAP_APP_PORT** is deprecated and you should use [**PORT**](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#PORT).

Try using `python` instead of `python3` in your Procfile. And try to add a `runtime.txt` file like https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/cloud-sql-database/blob/master/runtime.txt

Comment: I'm facing new errors and I have added them in my question. Please take a look at them.

Comment: The first ERR is not really an error, the second is missing details. Try using `python` instead of `python3` in your Procfile. And try to add a runtime.txt file like https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/cloud-sql-database/blob/master/runtime.txt

Comment: I tried but the result is the same. There's a timeout after 15 minutes. Each deployment takes around 20 minutes but ends up failing.

Comment: Is there a need to use that specific buildpack? You can remove that line from the manifest. In that cases there is no download needed because the local Python buildpack will be used. Python is detected based on the app characteristics

Comment: I removed it and instead of a timeout error, I'm simply getting an "unsuccessful start" message, just like in the beginning. I checked the error logs (which have been fully added in the question) and I noticed "Exit status 137 (out of memory)" error. Is that the main error or is there something else? If yes, what kind of memory error is it talking about? Should I increase my app's memory in manifest.yml? It is currently at 25 MB. Honestly, I have no idea how to set the memory, I just tried to use the least possible amount.

Comment: @SteveClay It didn't even start properly. Gave the message - "You have exceeded your organization's memory limit: app requested more memory than available
FAILED"

Comment: The memory limit is for all of the apps you have deployed, not just the current app. If you have other apps that you no longer need, try removing these. You can see all the apps you have with `cf apps`. You also may not need 256M, but might suffice with 128M.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was down-voted. There are several issues here and it's got the fix for all of them. For what it's worth, 25M is just to small to really run anything. There is some overhead in each container because there are a couple other small processes that run (an ssh daemon, envoy proxy, init process). My experience is that you can reliably run a small/basic Python/Flask app with 64M, but below that it's going to be very sensitive to what you're doing. And of course, it will vary depending on your app, you can certainly use way more memory than 64M.