# Exit status 137 (out of memory) error showing up on deploying Flask app in IBM CloudFoundry

Tags: python, github, flask, ibm-cloud

I deployed my Flask app but I'm getting an unsuccessful start message. Here are the error logs:

```
Invoking 'cf logs churn_predictor_mody --recent'...

Retrieving logs for app churn_predictor_mody in org smishrav2@gmail.com / space dev as smishrav2@gmail.com...

   2020-05-04T19:33:05.06+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T19:34:07.05+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T19:35:07.11+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T19:36:13.97+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
   2020-05-04T19:37:06.61+0530 [STG/0] OUT            Running setup.py install for pandas: finished with status 'done'
   2020-05-04T19:37:15.06+0530 [STG/0] OUT        Successfully installed Flask-1.1.2 Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-1.0.1 click-7.1.2 cycler-0.10.0 itsdangerous-1.1.0 joblib-0.14.1 kiwisolver-1.2.0 matplotlib-2.2.2 numpy-1.14.3 pandas-0.23.0 pyparsing-2.4.7 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 scikit-learn-0.22.2 scipy-1.4.1 six-1.14.0
   2020-05-04T19:37:15.51+0530 [STG/0] ERR        WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1 is available.
   2020-05-04T19:37:15.52+0530 [STG/0] ERR        You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
   2020-05-04T19:37:51.74+0530 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-05-04T19:37:51.74+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
   2020-05-04T19:37:51.74+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet...
   2020-05-04T19:37:51.74+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading build artifacts cache...
   2020-05-04T19:37:54.30+0530 [API/23] OUT Creating droplet for app with guid f29f90c2-ffb4-484d-ba8c-0fa55ceeafe9
   2020-05-04T19:37:54.75+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded build artifacts cache (112.8M)
   2020-05-04T19:38:02.02+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded droplet (142.4M)
   2020-05-04T19:38:02.06+0530 [STG/0] OUT Uploading complete
   2020-05-04T19:38:02.35+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell 69a6d7ce-7f16-4a8f-8cbe-9e4163ccc12b stopping instance ccd63041-fc2e-4cc0-8b35-55d25948d538
   2020-05-04T19:38:02.35+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell 69a6d7ce-7f16-4a8f-8cbe-9e4163ccc12b destroying container for instance ccd63041-fc2e-4cc0-8b35-55d25948d538
   2020-05-04T19:38:03.05+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 40a05280-064a-408d-abe4-a6db0e5f8a9c creating container for instance 0b7cd2f2-1cb6-4e83-5041-50b5
   2020-05-04T19:38:04.11+0530 [STG/0] OUT Cell 69a6d7ce-7f16-4a8f-8cbe-9e4163ccc12b successfully destroyed container for instance ccd63041-fc2e-4cc0-8b35-55d25948d538
   2020-05-04T19:38:04.15+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 40a05280-064a-408d-abe4-a6db0e5f8a9c successfully created container for instance 0b7cd2f2-1cb6-4e83-5041-50b5
   2020-05-04T19:38:05.16+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2020-05-04T19:38:17.36+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet (142.4M)
   2020-05-04T19:38:17.36+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2020-05-04T19:38:27.43+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 137 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T19:38:27.44+0530 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-05-04T19:38:33.12+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 40a05280-064a-408d-abe4-a6db0e5f8a9c stopping instance 0b7cd2f2-1cb6-4e83-5041-50b5
   2020-05-04T19:38:33.12+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 40a05280-064a-408d-abe4-a6db0e5f8a9c destroying container for instance 0b7cd2f2-1cb6-4e83-5041-50b5
   2020-05-04T19:38:33.14+0530 [API/4] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2020-05-04T19:38:33.18+0530 [API/4] OUT App instance exited with guid f29f90c2-ffb4-484d-ba8c-0fa55ceeafe9 payload: {"instance"=>"0b7cd2f2-1cb6-4e83-5041-50b5", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"40a05280-064a-408d-abe4-a6db0e5f8a9c", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 137 (out of memory)", "crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1588601313103432591, "version"=>"71b362a9-c192-4b3e-8143-f514c8ea64cb"}
   2020-05-04T19:38:33.30+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f4198bdc-ef6a-44cf-a21d-7a7d24072eaa creating container for instance 396d3f9f-dad8-4a5d-7c09-35bb
   2020-05-04T19:38:33.40+0530 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137
   2020-05-04T19:38:34.65+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 40a05280-064a-408d-abe4-a6db0e5f8a9c successfully destroyed container for instance 0b7cd2f2-1cb6-4e83-5041-50b5
   2020-05-04T19:38:35.34+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f4198bdc-ef6a-44cf-a21d-7a7d24072eaa successfully created container for instance 396d3f9f-dad8-4a5d-7c09-35bb
   2020-05-04T19:38:35.85+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2020-05-04T19:38:48.26+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet (142.4M)
   2020-05-04T19:38:48.26+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2020-05-04T19:39:02.34+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 137 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T19:39:02.37+0530 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-05-04T19:39:08.34+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f4198bdc-ef6a-44cf-a21d-7a7d24072eaa stopping instance 396d3f9f-dad8-4a5d-7c09-35bb
   2020-05-04T19:39:08.34+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f4198bdc-ef6a-44cf-a21d-7a7d24072eaa destroying container for instance 396d3f9f-dad8-4a5d-7c09-35bb
   2020-05-04T19:39:08.50+0530 [API/8] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2020-05-04T19:39:08.52+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell c8dbca73-4ffc-4bde-8362-0fe98e683c38 creating container for instance ef87529f-a34b-44ef-7e1b-2972
   2020-05-04T19:39:08.59+0530 [API/8] OUT App instance exited with guid f29f90c2-ffb4-484d-ba8c-0fa55ceeafe9 payload: {"instance"=>"396d3f9f-dad8-4a5d-7c09-35bb", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"f4198bdc-ef6a-44cf-a21d-7a7d24072eaa", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 137 (out of memory)", "crash_count"=>2, "crash_timestamp"=>1588601348330904116, "version"=>"71b362a9-c192-4b3e-8143-f514c8ea64cb"}
   2020-05-04T19:39:08.78+0530 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137
   2020-05-04T19:39:09.76+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell c8dbca73-4ffc-4bde-8362-0fe98e683c38 successfully created container for instance ef87529f-a34b-44ef-7e1b-2972
   2020-05-04T19:39:10.01+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2020-05-04T19:39:11.08+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell f4198bdc-ef6a-44cf-a21d-7a7d24072eaa successfully destroyed container for instance 396d3f9f-dad8-4a5d-7c09-35bb
   2020-05-04T19:39:21.05+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet (142.4M)
   2020-05-04T19:39:21.05+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2020-05-04T19:39:30.97+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 137 (out of memory)
   2020-05-04T19:39:30.98+0530 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-05-04T19:39:36.63+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell c8dbca73-4ffc-4bde-8362-0fe98e683c38 stopping instance ef87529f-a34b-44ef-7e1b-2972
   2020-05-04T19:39:36.63+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell c8dbca73-4ffc-4bde-8362-0fe98e683c38 destroying container for instance ef87529f-a34b-44ef-7e1b-2972
   2020-05-04T19:39:36.74+0530 [API/2] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2020-05-04T19:39:36.78+0530 [API/2] OUT App instance exited with guid f29f90c2-ffb4-484d-ba8c-0fa55ceeafe9 payload: {"instance"=>"ef87529f-a34b-44ef-7e1b-2972", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"c8dbca73-4ffc-4bde-8362-0fe98e683c38", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 137 (out of memory)", "crash_count"=>3, "crash_timestamp"=>1588601376635302163, "version"=>"71b362a9-c192-4b3e-8143-f514c8ea64cb"}
   2020-05-04T19:39:36.92+0530 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137
   2020-05-04T19:39:38.41+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell c8dbca73-4ffc-4bde-8362-0fe98e683c38 successfully destroyed container for instance ef87529f-a34b-44ef-7e1b-2972
   2020-05-04T19:40:32.21+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell be941519-9b3a-40c0-a9ed-75d587fe3a77 creating container for instance 8ec22bc9-1e0d-40bb-55ff-253b
   2020-05-04T19:40:33.66+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Cell be941519-9b3a-40c0-a9ed-75d587fe3a77 successfully created container for instance 8ec22bc9-1e0d-40bb-55ff-253b
   2020-05-04T19:40:34.05+0530 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
```

This is the link to my previous question regarding the same app with similar errors: [Flask app doesn't start successfully after deploying on IBM Toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61585764/flask-app-doesnt-start-successfully-after-deploying-on-ibm-toolchain)

This is my github repo: https://github.com/sthitaprajna-mishra/churn_prediction_v1_git

Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: If the credentials in your git are real, then they should be removed.

Comment: but how will my app function if I remove the credentials from my git repo?

Comment: How will you keep your account (safe) with exposing your creds to the world? Anyone has access to your resources right now. There is something like service binding, shared secrets, Key Protect as vault and others. In CF it is typically by service binding through VCAP.

Comment: What if I store my credentials in a config.py file (which I will add in a .gitignore file) and import from there in my app.py?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `manifest.yml` specifies `memory: 150M`. Increase it, and either "push" with a "restage" or "scale" your app as well.